# Mysql updating date field with 1 year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update

I have this query:

```
update prices_types_company1 set 'date'=DATE_ADD('date',INTERVAL 1 year)
```

which I am trying to execute directly in phpMyadmin to increase all date fields with 1 year but it returns error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''date'=DATE_ADD('date',INTERVAL 1 year)' at line 1

what is wrong with it and what other query I can execute to increase the date with 1 year. Field "date" is type date..

Thank you

Comment: use backticks instead of single quotes ` around date column

Comment: i tried that and than it returns error #1062 - Duplicate entry '1-1-18-2013-12-31' for key 2 because this field has unique attribute

Comment: What's the problem? You said that there shouldn't be any duplicates, so you get an error if you try to create one.

Comment: Barmar I don't know what is the problem but query refuse to update date field with 1 year.. Can you sugest Any other type of query to do the same?

Comment: @thecore7 I posted my answer copy paste this I already checked it works

Comment: Actualy guys after I checked I discovered the table was updated even with error so it works ! Thank you, I accept your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL behaves rather weird in a number of situations, update is one of them. You will have to do something like:

```
update prices_types_company1 
    set date=DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 1 year)
order by date desc;
```

to avoid duplicate key error. Example:

```
create table t (d date not null primary key);
insert into t (d) values ('2014-06-05 12:00:00'),('2014-06-06 12:00:00');
update t set d = DATE_ADD(d, interval 1 day);
    ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2014-06-06' for key 'PRIMARY'
update t set d = DATE_ADD(d, interval 1 day) order by d desc;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quotes and use backticks like this

```
UPDATE prices_types_company1 SET `date`=DATE_ADD(`date`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove all single qoutes:

```
update prices_types_company1 set date=DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 1 year)
```